# Why don't body CSS variables override the ones defined in the root?

Tags: css, css-variables

The question itself is pretty self-explanatory. I have the following code:

```css
:root {
  --brand-color: blueviolet;
  
  --button-background-color: var(--brand-color);
}
body {
  --brand-color: blue;
}

button {
  background-color: var(--button-background-color);
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button>Button</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the `body {...}` selector, I have overridden the `--brand-color` variable. The button is in the body, but the button's background color is still set to the `--brand-color` defined in the root. I understand that this is the default behavior of CSS variables, but can someone explain to me why this is happening and what is the correct way to override the variable here? Provided, I don't want to override it in the `button {...}` selector.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what's happening:

1. `--brand-color` is set to `blueviolet`
2. `--button-background-color` is set to the CURRENT VALUE of `--brand-color` (not a reference to the variable)
3. `--brand-color` value is set to `blue`

Since `--button-background-color` is never reset, it maintains the original value.

You could use the brand color directly and it would have the correct value.

```css
button {
    background-color: var(--brand-color);
    ...
}
```